# Tabs from json nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
[
{
    "idn" : "liquido",
    "categoria": "Aromatizante Ambiental Liquido",
    "productos": [
        {
            "nombre": "Canela"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "Chanel"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "Citrus"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "Coco"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "Floral"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "Manzanas"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "Spa Relax"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "Vainilla"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "idn" : "aerosol",
    "categoria": "Aromatizante Ambiental en Aerosol",
    "productos": [
        {
            "nombre": "Good Sense Jardin de Tuscan Neutralizador de Olores Aerosol"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "Good Sense Potpourri Neutralizador de Olores Aerosol"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "Good Sense No Smoke Eliminador de Olores Aerosol"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

I have this code, from a json file, i make a function, to make tabs, for each "categoria", but when i try a make "click" to the "li" element, doesn't work, it's like not make a click, but the html is generating correctly.

Even if add a "a" element,this not work. But

Any one, knows why?. Thanks

Comment: Where's your code to generate the click events?

Answer (score 0):

You did not show your client-side code. It is a problem with client-side code. Also you did not even said which language you use. Please provide more information. Please check `json.org` before you ask a question. Good Luck :)